# can i make android app using only html and css

Tags: android, html, css

Please tell whether I can make an app using HTML and CSS only and **NO** javascript .
I am not aware of any programming languages but I have an idea of making an android application.
So I want to make it however and please also suggest for if I could make for ios application.
if yes then what are the features I could use in that app.
like my app notifies you like alarm-clock so is that possible??

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no. Sorry, you will have to work a bit harder for your first app.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it only with HTML and CSS, you need a logic in your application, this is just layout.

You are not a programmer doesn't mean you can't learn, I suggest you a beginner course: https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837

This is really easy and you can follow the lessons when you have free time.
Good luck ;)

Comment: I have tried learning that but I found it difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an application for multi-platform with some hybrid technology like: PhoneGap, Cordova, ionic and ReactNative is now very hot.
But JAVASCRIPT is REQUIRED!